# VLOOKUP and Sheet Name using MID formula

Tags: worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a work sheet where VLOOKUP working properly but not work when i add a cell value that contain sheet name using formula

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

No issue at all, adding sheet name manually in that cell. but adding with formula i got error.

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps there are no problems with this part of the calculations, with this formula `MID(CELL())` (but this is not accurate). Please supplement your question with a formula with `VLOOKUP()` - there may be an error there. In addition, specify whether this workbook is already saved on disk or is it a new file that has not yet been saved?

Comment: Is this Microsoft Excel?

Comment: File saved on my disk. I can share to look at solution.

Comment: As has been stated, you left out something we *really* need to see, and that is the VLOOKUP() formula itself.  *How* you are suing this in your VLOOKUP() formula *absolutely* matters.  A few thoughts…  (a) are you appending a `’` before the sheet name and a `’!` after the sheet name before using it in a formula?  (b) are you placing all of this in an INDIRECT() statement before using it in a formula like VLOOKUP()?  The answers to both (a) and (b) have to be “yes” for it to work.